# How to start a new activity, send a string via putExtra and receive it in another activity while using Model View Presenter pattern?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, mvp

So I am using a Model View Presenter pattern for an android application and as far as I my understanding of MVP goes, the Views should be as passive as possible so in other words, all the logic should be done via the Presenter. 
That all being said, I cannot find out out how to start an activity and send a string which should be received in the new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a good sample for MVP Architecture

https://github.com/Rukey7/MvpApp